# how to exclude title band in jasper reports when exported as excel

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this at top of my jrxml

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="LineChart01" pageWidth="1400" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="1360" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="70d31602-bfb5-4388-9d80-87ea7a72f43d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="NEW_DATAADAPTER.xml"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="removeEmptySpaceBetweenRows" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeEmptySpaceBetweenColumns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.title" value="title"/>
    <!-- more records ... -->
</jasperReport>
```

How can I exclude the title band? I tried [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/526453/hiding-bands-csv-file). In that link question have few properties to hide some bands those didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your title band contains subreport? If yes then you need to use this

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.report.(sameValue)" value="Actual Sub Report Name"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.band.(sameValue)" value="detail"/>
```

You can change xlsx with pdf, csv, xls etc. I have used detail as value in my second property because my subreport contains only detail band. You can change this with your subreport band.

Comment: no i do not have sub report in title band it just has few text fields.

Comment: Are you getting when you set property to jrxml ? Which version of jasper are you using ?

Comment: jasper reports 6.0. you suggested above properties "if" i have a sub report in my title band. you didn't specify how to do "if not" :)

Comment: The same property should work what you have used in your jrxml.